# Catching Exceptions in Oracle on Solaris fails

Tags: c++, oracle, stored-procedures, exception, solaris

In our code we trying to catch an exception. This code has been working fine for years with different architectures and operating systems (x86, x64, SuSe Linux 11 SP2, Oracle 11g, Oracle 12c). Now we also tried out Solaris 11.3 on x86/64 and Sparc with Oracle 12c.

It turns out that we are not able to catch the exceptions and that the whole program crashes. We produce a shared object library which is then loaded into Oracle and used by a stored procedure. Within that stored procedure we might throw an exception but catch it and make it pretty for Oracle.

The combination of Solaris 11.3/Oracle 12c/x64  now behaves strange:
The extproc process is being killed and Oracle just delivers an `ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent` error message.

Please find an MVCE at https://gist.github.com/pgab/13ac10f4302d11cab45ba80584eeca0f.

The complete output on Solaris with SQL Developer is:

```
declare
  ret number;
begin
    "thrower".test_throw(ret);
end;
Error report -
ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent
ORA-06512: at "thrower.TEST_THROW", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 4
28576. 00000 -  "lost RPC connection to external procedure agent"
*Cause:    A fatal error occurred in either an RPC network connection,
           the extproc agent, or the invoked 3GL after communication had
           been established successfully.
*Action:   First check the 3GL code you are invoking; the most likely
           cause of this error is abnormal termination of the
           invoked "C" routine. If this is not the case, check for
           network problems. Correct the problem if you find it. If all
           components appear to be normal but the problem persists, the
           problem could be an internal logic error in the RPC transfer
           code.  Contact your customer support representative.
```

Also the used `/tmp/debug.log` produces just:

```
about to throw
```

In comparison the output with SuSe is:

```
declare
  ret number;
begin
    "thrower".test_throw(ret);
end;
Error report -
ORA-20001: foo
ORA-06512: at "thrower.TEST_THROW", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

And in `/tmp/debug.log`

```
about to throw
foo
```

To be even more confusing:

- The same code works perfectly fine on Solaris 11.3 on Sparc,
- A single executable is able to throw and catch exceptions properly.

Which bit am I missing here? Maybe it a special linker flag or something else which needs to be activated for Solaris or even for Oracle?

**Edit:**

With the hint of @Andrew Henle I was digging into compiler and linker versions being used within extproc and the library being produced using `strings -a` and scanning the output:
On Solaris liboragst contained the following strings (c.f. https://nopaste.xyz/?63251ef69b12e0ac#zgE4Hfagu08eBnSkbIWKcV/Zoux9X6UWw+AH2eGESxM=):

```
GNU C++ 4.8.2 -m64 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fPIC
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.11-1.2458
```

where as extproc (the process spawned by Oracle RDBMS to load the external procedure) contains this (c.f. https://nopaste.xyz/?913cef4a7fdd4c0d#cHkGRMpWn3IiFwpqv0auys4nn04wfrwtom3eIHEimLE=):

```
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.11-1.2329
Xa;O;p;F;R=Sun C 5.12 SunOS_i386 Patch 148918-06 2013/06/11;backend;raw;cd;
/opt/SunProd/studio12u3/solarisstudio12.3-148906-08/prod/bin/cc
```

But there is nothing at `/opt/SunProd/studio12u3` being installed.

Furthermore please find below the versions of gcc/g++ and ld:
Solaris:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
ld --version
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.11-1.2458
```

**2nd Edit:**

I have no managed to compile the library with Oracle's developerstudio but still get an ORA-28576 error instead of the wanted ORA-20001. It is a "clean" Solaris 11.3 installation with just Oracle Database, CMake and Developer Studio 12.6.

Cmake issues:

```
/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC   -DoraGST_EXPORTS -fpic -m64 -std=c++03 -g -KPIC -I/export/opt/ora12cg3d/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/public -o CMakeFiles/oraGST.dir/oGST_manual.cpp.o -c /export/home/paul/test/oGST_manual.cpp
```

and

```
/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC  -KPIC -fpic -m64 -std=c++03 -g -m64 -std=c++03 -G -hliboraGST.so -o liboraGST.so CMakeFiles/oraGST.dir/oGST_manual.cpp.o -lstdc++
```

`ldd -d liboraGST.so` yields:

```
libstdc++.so.6 =>        /opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/CC-gcc/lib/amd64/libstdc++.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/CC-gcc/lib/amd64/libgcc_s.so.1
libstatomic.so.1 =>      /opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/atomic/amd64/libstatomic.so.1
libCrunG3.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/64/libCrunG3.so.1
libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
librt.so.1 =>    /lib/64/librt.so.1
libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
```

For you reference you can find the output of `strings -a` at https://nopaste.xyz/?50daded482074bd3#9KLZaMYDiVBEFLLrTFV1UOY5ZRaZWnz006iBwSnCzMk=

Comment: What compiler(s)?  You need to be really careful that your shared object loads the correct C++ run-time libraries, and that those C++ run-time libraries are the same as any used by the Oracle process itself. Copies of different C++ run-times in the same executable don't work. And we can't say what linker flags you may or may not need because you haven't provided neither compile or link commands.

Comment: are you aware that "ORA-20001: foo" is user defined? As you know ora messages of 20000 are so. It may exist in a trigger.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've added this information, let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I am totally aware of that. This what the code should produce as it does on SuSe/Oracle combination but not on Solaris(x64)/Oracle but yet again on Solaris(Sparc)Oracle.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I now also manage to compile the extension with CC from developerstudio. It still ends up with an ORA-28576 instead of the customized ORA-20001. Any ideas are appreciated.